# notification with sound but without vibration and conversely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications, vibration

- How can i use local notification with sound but without vibration?
- And how can i use it conversely, with vibration but without sound?

**edit:**
while i read, i found one solution for vibration without sound:
(not appropriate to localnotifications in my case)
a) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
b) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
and as variant play silent sound, that will give vibration without sound effect.

and i can't use sound without vibration (we speak about local notifications). Am i right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i use local notification with sound but without vibration?

Vibration is always triggered if a sound is specified for the notification ( dependent on the user's settings, they may have Vibration turned off). I don't think there's currently any way of disabling vibrate for a sound-enabled notification.

> And how can i use it conversely, with vibration but without sound?

Your guess was correct, this one is easily achieved using a silent sound file (ensure it's less than 30 seconds, the limit imposed by the notification API).